# Random writing lines from url or without

Tags: c#

I'm fresh in c# i have an important question.

I want to make randomly text writer one line from url "list"

i have that code:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
string text = web.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/ky2qyTVz");
Colorful.Console.WriteLine("Codded by xxx - ", text);
```

This can be make with url but if u know how to make it without url u can edit this code.

But i want to make it writing in console only one of line from url randomly.
If any one can help me with this and make the final working code thanks <3
I tried a lot of things but i can't make it.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is not clear to me.  Please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question.

Comment: Yea i know that can be not clear to u i explain this now i wan't to write "text" from url/list randomly i mean e.g i  have 2 citations in url/list and i want that the program get one of it and write it in console.

Comment: How can you select citations from the website? Can you add some examples?

Comment: e.g this link: https://pastebin.com/raw/ky2qyTVz

Comment: I can not access this page, so please add what you have and what you expected to write in the console.

Comment: for example: i mean i have some citations and i want to program show one from list in console line

Comment: 'He travels the fastest who travels alone.'
'I don't know what to type.'

cictations

Comment: I have added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61049159/5519709), please check

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to `Split` web content to lines and select it randomly by using [`Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random) like that:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
string text = web.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/g064BJhZ");

var lines = text.Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None);
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomLineIndex = rnd.Next(0, lines.Count());
var randomline = lines[randomLineIndex];

Console.WriteLine("Codded by xxx - ", randomline);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

You do not know how many lines you received. You can use a string reader to loop over the lines to get the count of lines.

You need to generate a random number that is between 0 and the number of lines. You can use the Random class for this.

Putting these together you can use some like the code below:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            string text = web.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/g064BJhZ"); //this is your call, but it only returns 2 lines. Not very interesting.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //we make a test string with more lines:
            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i ++)
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"This is line {i}");
            }

            List<string> lines = new List<string>(); //we want to hold all the lines
//you could be more efficient here, just showing you an easy to understand 
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0) //while we have more lines
                {
                    lines.Add(sr.ReadLine()); //add this line to our list

                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //now lets output some random lines:
            {
//this says using a random number, between 0 and the number of lines,
// write the line to the console.
                Console.WriteLine(lines[RandomNumber(0, lines.Count()-1)]);
            }


        }
        public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.Next(min, max);
        }
    }
}
```

My output is:
This is line 4
This is line 12
This is line 12
This is line 19
This is line 21